# How do I disable the option + space full screen slideshow shortcut?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, applescript, automator

I want this shortcut to run an apple script to open a new iTerm window.

I can't when I use the shortcut in `Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services` it does not register, and I think it's because it's already taken by the slideshow.

I can't find the slideshow hotkey in `Keyboard > Shortcuts`, so maybe I can disable it somewhere else?

[Article about the full-screen slideshow](https://osxdaily.com/2012/09/06/8-tricks-mac-os-x-full-screen-slideshow/). Use it on your desktop or in any folder see it in action.

More specific:

This is the script

```
if application "iTerm" is running then
    tell application "iTerm"
        create window with default profile
    end tell
else
    activate application "iTerm"
end if
```

[image]

and I have it as a service in the keyboard shortcuts:

[image]

If I run it in automator, it works fine. When I use the shortcut it's not working.

Comment: I tested by swapping 'Show FInder Search Window' from Cmd/Opt/Space to Opt/Space & it worked just fine. Have you tested a non-conflicting key command for your service?

Comment: Are you on Big Sur? Just tried shift/opt/space and it's not working. Service works however when using it from the context menu

Comment: I'm still on Mojave, can't test anything newer, sorry.